# What is the function of "pretty" in "pretty inefficient"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Could you tell me what is the role of the word in bold in the following sentence :

> Worrying is **pretty** inefficient.

Comment: Have you used a dictionary. They list the roles that each word has.  What are the options for "pretty".  Can you now answer your own question?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty is an adverb in this sentence, meaning *quite*, *fairly*. See Google/Oxford Dictionary:

> **Adverb**
>
> to a moderately high degree; fairly.
>   "he looked pretty fit for his age"

Note that this usage of "pretty" is **informal** in register.